# How many measurements does a typical phasor meqasurement unit (PMU) capture?

Tags: transmission-line, three-phase, power-engineering, phasor

How many phasor measurements (voltage amplitude and phase angle) does a typical PMU capture from 1) transmission and 2) distribution lines? is it one, three, or more? Does this depend on the topology of transmission/distribution grid, and how do they differ?

I would appreciate it if you could explain in details.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a typical PMU?

Comment: @Andyaka  for example http://www.arbiter.com/catalog/product/model-1133a-power-sentinel.php#tabs-2.

Comment: Have you tried asking the supplier?

Comment: I haven't asked them yet. Do all transmission and distribution lines have three phasors? can it be less or more?

Comment: Have you tried googling or wikipedia - they are normally good at generic questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

The PMU samples power at the nominal frequency of **50** or **60** Hz and reports on current and voltage at a typical rate of **48** **samples-per-cycle** with **one micro-second** accuracy. The output of the PMU is a stream of time-tagged synchrophasors at a rate of up to **60 samples-per-second**.
 https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/smart-grid-communication-enabled/9781118820247/OEBPS/9781118820247_epub_c_13.htm